# SAS: If a column has values that are in a array

Tags: arrays, if-statement, sas

Below is an example of what I'm doing. I want to get the subset of the dataset.(i.e the  rows that have these letters in the Alphabet column). I want to select only those records where Transport_company is either Hyundai, Toyota or Ford.

```
Data arrayInIf;
set OldTable;
array Car_array {3}a b c('Hyundai', 'Toyota', 'Ford');
If Transport_company ^= Car_array
Then
    Delete;
Run;
```

Whats wrong? How can i get this to work.

Ok, so sample data would be:

- Zip    Transport_Company        No. Sold
- 12345    Hyundai                   10
- 90145    NASA                      50
- 20202    Toyota                    30
- 40002    Harley Davidson           5
- 10000    Ford                      15

So, I would only want to keep all the rows related to car companies

Comment: You may post a sample of the data, which will be helpful for answers contribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robbie's right that if your data isn't already in an array you shouldn't use array methods, as it's adding extra complication - in is fine.

However, if it *is* in an array already, `whichc` (or `whichn` for numerics) is a good solution.

```
data oldtable;
input Zip Transport_Company $ No_Sold;
datalines;
12345 Hyundai 10
90145 NASA 50
20202 Toyota 30
40002 HarleyDavidson 5
10000 Ford 15
;;;;
run;

Data arrayInIf;
  set OldTable;
  array Car_array{3} $ ('Hyundai', 'Toyota', 'Ford');
  If whichc(transport_company,of car_array[*])=0
  Then
    Delete;
Run;
```

In general, the *best* way to do this is to construct a format.  Look up `PROC FORMAT CNTLIN` for how to do this from a dataset; or you can do this in code:

```
proc format;
  value $automakerF
    'Hyundai','Toyota','Ford'=1
    other=0;
quit;

data fmtInIf;
  set oldtable;
  if put(transport_company,automakerF.) ne '1' 
    then delete;
 run;
```

This has the value of separating your data from your code, plus you can bring the automaker names in from a dataset if you want; as well, you can do all of your different industries in one format as well.  It's also very fast, faster than a bunch of if statements or the in statement.

Comment: You can make your second approach faster by changing the `if ... then delete` to a `where` statement in the data step.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to use array here. If you just want to select rows based on multiple values, use the `in` keyword. The concept of array in SAS is different from some other programming languages which usually see array as a set of string and numerical values. The array in SAS stores a set of columns (variables).

```
data b;
set a;
where Transport_Company in ('Hyundai', 'Toyota', 'Ford');
run;
```

The output:

```
   Obs     Zip      Transport_Company     Sold
    1     12345     Hyundai               10
    2     20202     Toyota                30
    3     10000     Ford                  15
```

As @alex has mentioned in his comment, if you need to filter rows based on a long list, `where...in ()` will become cumbersome. In this case, my solution would be usually creating a new set with these names.

```
Transport_Company

Hyundai
Toyota
Ford
...
BMW
```

Then do a simple pseudo-merge (conditional selection) using `proc sql`. This should be fairly fast.

```
proc sql;
    create table c as
    select a.* from a, cars where a.Transport_Company = cars.Transport_Company;
quit;
```

Comment: In general it's more efficient to use `where Transport_Company in ...` than `if ...` since the former only reads the records from the input dataset matching the condition, whereas the latter reads all records and then subsets.

Comment: Also note that if the sample data presented is a toy example and many more auto makers are actually considered, using `in` becomes cumbersome. Still, +1.

Comment: @Alex thanks for your comment. I did not have much impression about the performance difference between `in` and `where`. Edited.